# Clion linux environment modules

Tags: linux, clion, environment-modules

I'm trying to setup a project using clion ins linux but when the import its made i get an error for not being able to found eigen 3
Eigen3 was installed as an enviroment-module (module load eigen3) and in fact I can compile this project when i use the linux shell.
So I suspect that I had to say clion how to use environment-modules, something that I can't found on the web.

Answer (score 0):

You must load your environment-module before you start CLion.

One way to do so is to launch CLion from the terminal after `module load eigen3`.

The other way (more distribution-dependent, might not always work) is to load the module in your `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile`) so that the module is loaded when you log in and is available when you open any program.

Do not forget to reset the CMake cache.

Comment: Thanks, use the terminal after module load had worked.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method would be to simply set the necessary environment variables by going to:

**Run -> Edit Configurations...** and then edit the **Environment variables** section:

[image]

You only have to do this once. After that every time you open the project you have the correct environment variables.