# Clion linux environment modules and OpenCV

Tags: c, cmake, opencl

I am searching on how to force CMake to find OpenCL

My `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
find_package(OpenCL REQUIRED)
add_executable(test main.c)
target_link_libraries (test OpenCL::OpenCL)
```

and before CMake is able to find OpenCL I have to execute

```
module load CUDA
```

The server is using https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html

If I run `cmake` using SSH its all fine, but when I want to do that in CLion its not able to find OpenCL, like CLion would completly ignore module load command.

I also placed this command in `~/.bash_profile` which caused ssh connection to always find OpenCL (no need to execute `module load CUDA` command everytime I log in).

Also looked here: [Clion linux environment modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47092761/clion-linux-environment-modules)

But no use, CLion is still not able to find OpenCL, so not sure what to do now, can I somehow in `CmakeLists.txt` manually specify path to OpenCL Libs and include that instead, because I have them in `/ceph/grid/home/ss264hg/CUDA/cuda-11.0`